# SUMIF in R multiple criteria

Tags: r

I have data frame like this:

```
        Date Trade.Name            SKU Sales.in.USD Sum.Units Sales.in.Loc.currency
1 01.03.2010     Brand1 Brand1 CAPS 32      37994.9    4135.5             1123107.3
2 01.03.2010     Brand1 Brand1 CAPS 16      37918.5    5752.7             1167896.0
3 01.03.2010     Brand1 Brand1 CAPS 48      37875.0    2888.9             1245879.5
4 01.04.2010     Brand1 Brand1 CAPS 16      37192.4    6427.6             1099386.2
5 01.04.2010     Brand1 Brand1 CAPS 16      36591.8    5536.0             1073304.0
6 01.03.2010     Brand2 Brand2 CAPS 28          6.4       0.7                 207.4
7 01.03.2010     Brand2 Brand2 CAPS 28          6.4       0.7                 226.5
8 01.04.2010     Brand2 Brand2 CAPS 28          6.3       0.6                 195.4
9 01.04.2010     Brand2 Brand2 CAPS 28          6.3       0.6                 196.1
```

And I want aggregate it by `SKU` and get data frame like this one:

```
        Date Trade.Name Sales.in.USD    Sum.Units Sales.in.Loc.currency
1 01.03.2010     Brand1 113788.39180 113788.39180          113788.39180
2 01.04.2010     Brand1  73784.26045  73784.26045           73784.26045
3 01.03.2010     Brand2     12.71363     12.71363              12.71363
4 01.04.2010     Brand2     12.59949     12.59949              12.59949
```

I know I can use `dplyr` package but I don't know how to summarize it by multiple criteria: by `Date` and by `SKU`

Comment: Did you have a look at the [introduction do dplyr](http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html)? Basically you just need to `group_by(Date, SKU)` and then `summarize(...)`. There are already quite a few examples of `dplyr` code and `group_by` is used in many of those cases.

Comment: There are six different combinations of `SKU` and `Date` in your data set, why your output contains only four?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/dplyr.html

In the following i'll assume your data frame is named df.

```
require(dplyr)

df <- group_by(df, Date, SKU)

df.summary <- summarise(df, 
              sales = sum(Sales.in.USD), 
              units = sum(Sum.Units), 
              curr = sum(Sales.in.Loc.currency)
              )
```

I think this will do the trick.

Comment: There is also a `summarise_each` function

Comment: +1, you can also consider using the chain operator `%>%` so that `df.summary <- df %>% group_by(Date, SKU) %>% summarise(sales = sum(Sales.in.USD))`

Comment: @RenéMartínez - see the vignette - just updated the link, does a better job than I can

Answer (score 2):

Since you didn't explicitly say that this have to be a `dplyr` solution, here's a `data.table` solution which is as fast

I also, don't undertand your data, as it seems like you have six unique combinations between `Date` and `SKU`, wile your desired output shows only four. It seems that the only way to reach the desired output is by using the `Trade.Name` column, so here goes

```
library(data.table)
setDT(temp)[, lapply(.SD, sum), by = list(Date, Trade.Name), .SDcols = -c("SKU")]
```

Which results in

```
##          Date       Trade.Name Sales.in.USD Sum.Units Sales.in.Loc.currency
## 1: 01.03.2010 Brand1Brand1CAPS     113788.4   12777.1             3536882.8
## 2: 01.04.2010 Brand1Brand1CAPS      73784.2   11963.6             2172690.2
## 3: 01.03.2010 Brand2Brand2CAPS         12.8       1.4                 433.9
## 4: 01.04.2010 Brand2Brand2CAPS         12.6       1.2                 391.5
```